# Duplicate checker when trying to insert 2 leads at once marks both as duplicates

Tags: apex

I've got an apex class that takes incoming leads and converts them to person accounts. If an incoming lead is considered a duplicate, it'll find the id of the person account and use that person account id in the `..setAccountId` method. So far so good. My issue is that if I try to insert two leads simultaneously (e.g with a loop in the developer console), it'll mark both leads as duplicates, and not convert any of them at all and I'm just stuck with two un-converted leads. Here's the code below:

```
public static void assignAndConvertLeads(List<Id> leadIds) {

    List<Lead> allLeadsReceived = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :leadIds];

    LeadStatus convertedLeadStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true LIMIT 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> massLeadConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for (Lead currentlead :allLeadsReceived) {
        Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvert.setLeadId(currentlead.Id);
        leadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertedLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
        leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);
        massLeadConvert.add(leadConvert);
    }


    Database.DMLOptions allowSaveAll = new Database.DMLOptions();
    allowSaveAll.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
    Map<Id, List<Id>> leadsToExistingAccount = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    if(!massLeadConvert.isEmpty()) {
        List<Id> leadsThatAlreadyExists = new List<Id>();
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(massLeadconvert, false);
        // set 'false' to allow converting if no duplicates found
        for(Database.LeadConvertResult lead :lcr) {
            for (Database.Error error :lead.getErrors()) {
                if(error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
                    Database.DuplicateError duplicateError =(Database.DuplicateError) error;
                    Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = duplicateError.getDuplicateResult();

                    Datacloud.MatchResult [] matchResults = duplicateResult.getMatchResults();

                    Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult = matchResults [0];

                    Datacloud.MatchRecord [] matchRecords = matchResult.getMatchRecords();

                    for (Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord :matchRecords) {
                        leadsThatAlreadyExists.add(lead.getLeadId());
                        leadsToExistingAccount.put(matchRecord.getRecord().Id, leadsThatAlreadyExists);
                    }
                }


                List<Database.LeadConvert> newMassLead = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
                for (Id accountId :leadsToExistingAccount.keySet()) {
                    for (Id leadIdInMap :leadsToExistingAccount.get(accountId)) {
                        Database.LeadConvert newLeads = new Database.LeadConvert();
                        newLeads.setLeadId(leadIdInMap);
                        newLeads.setConvertedStatus(convertedLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
                        newLeads.setAccountId(accountId);
                        newLeads.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);
                        newMassLead.add(newLeads);
                    }

                }
                List<Database.LeadConvertResult> convertedLeadsToExistingAccount = Database.convertLead(newMassLead, allowSaveAll);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, `for (Database.Error error :lead.getErrors())` part of the method is what's causing issues when I try to insert two leads at once. Ideally, If I were to insert more than one record at the time, I'd like to convert one of them and mark the others as duplicates. Hope that makes sense..

Comment: Did you try passing your "allowSaveAll" variable to the first convertLead() call? Why are you creating it if it's not passed? This could allow the transaction to partially succeed when dups are found.

Comment: What do you mean? If I use the `allowSaveAll` on the first `convertLead()` - I won't catch duplicates, it'll just save everything into a new person account, won't it?

Comment: So when you pass 2 leads, if you put some system.debug() on the duplicate errors, are both leads tagged as duplicates?

Comment: Yes exactly, both get marked as duplicates

Comment: Then it sounds to be like Database.convertLead() doesn't allow for partial success when one of the records is a duplicate. There's no enough documentation about this online, if you have premier support, you should log a case.

Comment: So no work around for this?

Comment: Log a case with support if you have premier , otherwise nothing I can think of